# JavaScript: Calling functions from an Array

Tags: javascript

I have followed the answer to a previous question but I am not getting the results.
I am generating a random number and based on the number, I want to call 1 of four functions:

```
var functionArray[single, double, triple, quadruple];

function main() {
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * functionArray.length);
    x = functionArray[ranNum](); /* is this the way to call the function? */
}

/* example of one function in the array */
function single() {
    /* do stuff */
    return x;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem here with the code

Comment: var functionArray=[single, double, triple, quadruple];

Answer (score 7):

You are initializing the array wrong:

```
var functionArray[single, double, triple, quadruple];
```

Should be:

```
var functionArray = [single, double, triple, quadruple];
```

Then it should work!

---

```
x = functionArray[ranNum]();
```

> is this the way to call the function?

Yes, you can call it this way. But it might be more clear if you just execute [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
x = functionArray[ranNum].call();
```

---

Also note that you are using [reserved words](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp), like `double`. You are better off avoiding these.

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: @StrugglewithAndres You can accept this answer if it fits your needs! :)